# RStudio: Prompt line cannot run

Tags: rstudio, command-prompt

Sometimes when I'm working on RStudio the command prompt `>` doesn't appear and I can't even save the script.

This time it happened after I was trying to a load a package.

How can I get over this?

Comment: You're going to have to work out a way to make this reproducible if you want help with it.

Comment: Now it has happened after this instruction: `suomi<-read_file("malti.txt")`, when I had ran the same line and had no problems...

Comment: `read_file` is in the `readr` package.  Next time it happens, see if that function or package is involved again.